# Google maps - Facebook Places fake location using JSON

Tags: php, json, google-maps, geolocation

I am doing some research regarding location based social networking and I am trying to see whether I can fake a location by modifying the JSON that google returns to the Firefox browser.

Firstly, I have typed about:config in the firefox browser and got all the config settings up and changed the param of geo.wifi.uri to a page that returns JSON location below.

```
 <?php 

 header('Content-type: application/json');

 $longitude = "-73.98626";

 $latitude = "40.75659";

 $accuracy = "10";

 $geoArray = array( 'location'=>array(

         'latitude'=>$latitude,

         'longitude'=>$longitude,

         'accuracy'=>$accuracy ) ) ;

 $geoJson = json_encode( $geoArray ) ;

 echo $geoJson ;

 ?>
```

It has got to a stage where I can select a place and the check in button appears but when i press it, it just says loading..

I am using a firefox user agent iphone 3.0 setting to get the check-in option

Answer (score 0):

Does your faked location work in something like this: http://html5demos.com/geo ? There is an `access_token` field in the expected response that your JSON is missing: try adding that. And you may want to add an `address` field as well. This is the structure you need:

```
    {"location":
        {"latitude": 40.75659,
         "longitude": -73.98626,
         "address":{"country":"United States","country_code":"US","region":"<statename>",
    "city":"<city name>","street":"<street name>","street_number":"<number>","postal_code":"<zip>"},"accuracy":10.0},
"access_token":"<honestly not sure what this is or how it is interpreted>"}
```